# How to set lower than 800 x 600 to secondary monitor

Tags: display, resolution, external-display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an old analog monitor that its resolution is lower than 800x600.

I need to set it as my secondary monitor.

But the lowest resolution of windows is just 800x600

How to force windows to set lower than 800x600 resolution to the secondary monitor?

Comment: You haven't indicated what operating system you are using.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Windows Xp SP3 & NVIDIA

Comment: I dont do nvidia, but XP has a "list all modes" button in the advanced options in the display control pannel, that is known to at least show all possible modes a display card is capable of, and 640x480 is usually possible. I believe in XP it was also a way to get to the other possible resolutions.

Comment: If the resolution is less than 800x600, it is probably ancient and may lack the plug and play protocol that current systems look for.  Even if it came with drivers and you still have the floppy disk and a way to read it, the drivers probably wouldn't be compatible.  The current drivers typically get information from the monitor for what resolutions will work.  So your solution is probably going to require forcing a manual setting.  This doesn't answer your question but maybe it will help focus on where to look.